# jquery event with legend tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display content inside fieldset by using onclick event, I have successfully done this, but the content contains multiple check boxes and when I click on one of the checkbox then the content inside fieldset is disappear and am unable to check further checkboxes. Here is my source code.

```
<div>
   <fieldset class="majorpoints">
  <legend class="majorpointslegend"><c:out value="${clist.key}" /></legend>
  <div class="hiders" style="display:none" >
  <table align=center border=1 width="50%">
  <tr style='background:#002232'>
  <th><font color=#FFFFFF size="2"><b>Sr.No.</b></font></th>
  <th><font color=#FFFFFF size="2"><b>USER NAME</b></font></th>                                           
 <th><font color=#FFFFFF size="2"><b>SELECT</b></font></th>                                          
 </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${clist.value}" var="ltrate" varStatus="innerLoop">
   <tr>     
                                                                  <td><c:out value="${innerLoop.index+1}"/></td>                                                                                                                    <td><c:out value="${ltrate.name}" /></td>
                                                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cllist_item" value="ltrate.linkID"></td>

</tr>
</c:forEach> 
                                                   </table>                                    
 </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

jquery code :-

```
$('.majorpoints').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.hiders').toggle();
});
```

So I don't want to disappear content after clicking on checkbox I want to keep this steady and it will only disappear when I click on legend i.e. onclick event is happen specifically on legend, if anyone have experience about this then please let me know.

Comment: Please show the "*[MCVE]*" code in order that we can reproduce your problem and show how to solve it.

Comment: where is your code

Comment: Provide some source code...

Comment: now I updated my question, added source code.

Comment: .hiders is not child of legend. Try $(this).next(), maybe...

Comment: Please don't use `<font>` ... it's been dead for 20 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing onclick for fieldset and as checkbox is also part of fieldset, when you click on checkbox it is closing fieldset because of event. Write onclick for legend as below.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.majorpointslegend').click(function(){
          $(".majorpoints").find('.hiders').toggle();
      });
  });
```